# When _id is present in the projection, is the index on _id used for the query?

Tags: mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-3.4

My query is

```
db.new.find({'a':{'$gt':200}, 'b':{'$lt': 30}}, 
            {'a':1, 'c':1}
).sort({'c':-1})
```

Indexes present are `(a,b), (a,c), (c), (a,b,c), (_id)`

When I check with `explain('allPlansExecution')`, I see that the index on `_id` is not used anywhere. However, since `_id` has not been suppressed in the projection, shouldn't it be used? Is there any possibility of it being used implicitly in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need (in that query) to use _id index. There is no sort nor selection what need that index. Second, index (a,b) is not needed, it takes space and extra effort to keep updated. Index (a,b,c) answers all questions when keys a and b is queried.